Multi stage builds made my Python Docker image larger. Why?
When using normal one stage build Dockerfile, the final image is 216MB; but when using a multi-stage build approach shown below, I got a final image of 227MB. Why is this?
# This multi stage build Dockerfile actually makes the image larger! :(
FROM python:3.10.14-slim-bookworm AS base

LABEL authors="X"

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV ENVIRONMENT=production
ENV PYTHONPATH=/app

WORKDIR /app

FROM base AS build

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt && \
    rm requirements.txt

FROM base AS final

# cleaning up unused files
RUN  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY --from=build /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/


COPY ./src /app/src
# Expose port 8000 for FastAPI server
EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "/app/src/main.py"]

The requirements.txt file only contains 4 packages:
fastapi==0.111.0
loguru==0.7.2
aiohttp[speedups]==3.9.5
boto3==1.34.128


build is just this, installing packages with pip without writing any cache:
COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt && \
    rm requirements.txt

And final does this, copying everything that pip installed:
COPY --from=build /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/

So you’ve saved the size of requirements.txt and doubled the size of whatever already existed in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ before pip.
There’s just not much reason to use a multi-stage build with this starting point, as-is.
(Note that RUN  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* also creates a new layer to hold deletions, increasing size very slightly and not decreasing it.)

The typical pattern for multi-stage Python builds involves (a) installing into a virtual environment and not trying to COPY the system Python tree over, and (b) typically involves libraries with C extensions that need to be compiled, but where you don't need the C toolchain to run the application.
